Fix one rule using Eslint (semi-colon)
I'm trying to eliminate all the semi-colons of my Vue project and I've searched how to do it with eslint command line. I've fount this pattern :
eslint --no-eslintrc --fix --rule 'rule definition here'
However, I've tried different implementations with no success :
1) eslint --no-eslintrc --fix --rule 'semi: false'
2) eslint --no-eslintrc --fix --rule 'semi: 0'
3) eslint --no-eslintrc --fix --rule 'semi: 0' .
3) eslint '**/*.{js,vue,ts}' --no-eslintrc --fix --rule 'semi: 0'
3) eslint --no-eslintrc --fix --rule 'semi: ['error','never']'

It seems I still didn't come across the right sintaxis.
Any idea on this?
Thank you in advance for your suggestions,
PS: I have errors like :
ESLint: 8.57.1
No files matching the pattern "['error','never']'" were found.
Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.
or
ESLint: 8.57.1
No files matching the pattern "0'" were found.
Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.

Finally, I came up with this command :
(using parsers to recognize nuxt vue and typescript languages)
"fix-one-rule": "eslint --fix --parser vue-eslint-parser --parser-options \"{'parser': '@typescript-eslint/parser'}\" --rule \"{'semi': ['error', 'never']}\""

this one didn't show any console error, however it didn't fix the semi-commas neither, so I decided just to use the Eslint extension, hover to one of this warnings and inside the Quick-fix, just select correct all instances of this error in this page. It is not optimal because I need to go through all the files of the project, but it is one option.
